# Menu not absolute href compare with location href issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I have a code for menu, that compares `href` of menu item and URL and give class active, if compare is true.

Code

```
$(".gallery-navigation-container ul li a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == location.href) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active-el");
    }
});
```

On another site i have a problem, link in menu item is not absolute like http//: and so on, it is simply like `/about/` and compare is false.

Question: How to compare it to get active class to active element?

**UPDATE**

Try to use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var url = window.location.href;
        $('.navigation a').filter(function() {
             return this.href == url;
        }).addClass('better-active');
    });
```

No errors but no result...no class added. It deletes href in link when it is current page...haha

**Update 2**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var url = window.location.href;
        $('.navigation ul li a').each(function() {
         return $(this).attr("href") == url;
       }).addClass('better-active');
    });
```

It works, but delete current item href and get each item class...is it any way to fix it? Filter function gives nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `location.pathname` instead of href

```
 var path = window.location.pathname;
 path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
 path = decodeURIComponent(path);

 $(".gallery-navigation-container ul li a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href") === path.substring(0, $(this).attr("href").length)) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active-el");
    }
 });
```

Check this [example](http://www.itworld.com/article/2832973/development/setting-an-active-menu-item-based-on-the-current-url-with-jquery.html) for the similar implementation details

Comment: Did you try after my edit? $(this).attr("href").length..?

Comment: yep, i try, but nothing changes

Comment: what u meant by nothing changes, u stil have error or its not adding class?..also don't simply copy and try the same method, you might have to make changes as per your html, or share a fiddle